# Vice-versa Erdos conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, cellular-automata

Erdos conjectured that, except $1, 4$ and $256$,  no power of $2$ is a sum of distinct powers of $3$.

A vice-versa conjecture may be: except $1$, $9$ and $81$ all powers of $3$ contains two consecutive powers of $2$ in theirs binary expansions?

We can generate the powers $(3^n)$ as a cellular automata where the n-th line represent the binary expansion of $3^n$ and we can observe that the conjecture still verified as showed in the next images (with respectively 128 lines and 1024 lines).
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry!  I mean two consecutive powers of 2 in their binary expansions

Comment: Yes, that edit make the question meaningful.

Comment: Most likely, your conjecture is true, but if so, proving it is not likely to be any easier than for a proof of the Erdos conjecture (assuming that's true as well).